# Does there exist such a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, complex-numbers, vectors, direct-sum

Let $X,Y \subset \mathbb{C}^3$ with $X=\text{span}\{\begin{bmatrix}
         1\\
         2 \\
         3\\
        \end{bmatrix}\}$ 
and $Y=\text{span}\{\begin{bmatrix}
         1 \\
         1 \\
         2\\
        \end{bmatrix}\}$.
Does there exist a subspace $Z\subset \mathbb{C}^3$ such that $\mathbb{C}^3 = X \oplus Z$ and $\mathbb{C}^3 = Y \oplus Z$. If so, describe this subspace. If not, explain why.

I don't know how to approach this question. My intuition tells me such a subspace $Z$ cannot exist but I don't know how to prove this. I have played a bit with random vectors and I've tried proving that $X \cap Z \neq Y \cap Z = 0$ but I wasn't able to do this. Could someone help me out.

Comment: Note you should have $X,Y\subset\Bbb C^3$, not $\in$. :)

Comment: The fact that the scalar field is $\Bbb C$ instead of $\Bbb R$ isn't really relevant to the solution, so it turns out we can gain intuition by thinking with $\Bbb R^3$ instead - $3$D Euclidean space. The conditions $\Bbb R^3=X\oplus Z$ and $\Bbb R^3=Z\oplus Y$ means we need to find a plane $Z$ which does not contain either $X$ nor $Y$ (since a plane not containing a line is enough for the plane and line to span a $3$D subspace). This should be obviously true!

Answer (score 1):

Any $2$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbf C^3$ which contains neither $X$ nor $Y$ will do the trick.

Comment: Absolutely.$\phantom{aaa}$